# Contacts importer for phpfox

Tags: phpfox

Is there any free module available for contacts import in phpfox. I could find openinviter, unfortunately the downloaded file was corrupted/extracted contains a single file only. I need contacts importer of yahoo, gmail, hotmail and facebook.

Please help me.

Comment: no there are no free module for contact importer.

Comment: [CloudSponge](http://cloudsponge.com) is free to try (and paid for production domain), but it works fine integrated with any HTML page or directly with [PHP](http://cloudsponge.com/integrations/php). And it imports contacts from all sources you've listed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a plain database, sql or csv text file, you need to do it manually. I havent seen an raw uploader at least on my version. When you upgrade, it takes your pre existing database to import to the new version, but I dont think, or havent seen one for external data. But is fairly simple. There are about 4 tables to update. First is the user table. You need to emulate exact same fields, use an editor such notepad++ to get the structure from a backup SQL file. If your file is big, then use MS Excel, and save it as CSV then you edit in Notepad++ any missing sql sintax.

After you import those users into you main users table, then you need to setup the other companion tables (relational to users). On my version there are 4 aditional tables that may need to be syncronized with users table. (Need to add them there otherwise, cant visualize the properties of new members, such as pages, profile, etc)

NEW IMPORTED MEMBERS TABLES :

```
phpfox_user (main table)
phpfox_user_count 
phpfox_user_space
phpfox_user_field
phpfox_user_activity
```

Once you setup all those files, then you have all your new users ready to login. 
Just remember, assign them a known password on the password field and salt field, use a previously created user password and give then all your new users that same password (for first time login), then next time they login you can require them to change the password to a new one.

If you need any help, let me know. Cheers